# jquery datatables mRender retrieve column options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to render the cell value using some values I have stored in the column options, but I can't see an obvious way to access the currently rendering column.

Attaching to the source data seems redundant and could end up with a very large json response.

e.g.

```
$('#foo').dataTable({
    sAjaxSource : 'source.php',
    aoColumns : [
        {
            someExtraValue : 'bar'
            mRender : function(data, type, full) {
                // some how get the column's options for this cell
                return data + column.someExtraValue;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

return data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index value for `aoColumns` if you use the `fnCreatedCell` function within the `aoColumnDefs` settings option.

This way you can manipulate the created cell after it has been rendered.

```
$('#foo').dataTable({
    sAjaxSource : 'source.php',
    aoColumns : [
        {
            someExtraValue : 'bar'
        }
    ],
    aoColumnDef : [
        {
            aTargets : [0],
            nCreatedCell :  function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                var settings = $(this).fnSettings();
                var myVal    = settings.aoColumns[iCol].someExtraValue;
                $(nTd).append(myValue);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```